# How i get the similarity of phrases in C# .NET

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a sql database with data about headers of news. Example:

```
id  title
867 MPE consegue inverter julgamento                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
868 Defensoria P blica realiza licita                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
869 Prefeitos eleitos de todas as partes do Estado                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
870 Inc ndio deixa 80 pessoas desabrigadas                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
871 Carlos Amastha visita parlamentares                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
872 Defensoria P blica requer anula  o                                                                                                                                                                                                
873 Marcelo Miranda diz que n o possui obriga  o                                                                                                                                                                   
874 Ex-assessor diz que Coimbra lhe deu dois cheques
```

I need to get each title and see if there are other news to talk about the same subject.

How i do it? My plataform is .Net and use sql server 2012.

Comment: SQL Full text indexing might be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to put a Full-Text Index on this column and/or table.  It's a complex subject, but you can start reading up on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: This approach considers synonyms?

Comment: Yes, check out the Thesaurus File feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx